# String "in" into Python operator `in`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have string `"in"` and I would like to transform it into `in` operator in Python. For other operators I have `operator.add` etc but what with `in`?

Comment: Did you look in https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions?

Comment: What do you mean that you want to transform a string into an operator? That doesn't make much sense to me. Are you looking for `operator.contains()`? Do you have some code that you can share where we might be able to understand what you are trying to do?  This feels like a vague [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

`in` operator is a shortcut for builtin function `operator.contains`

It can be used like so:

```py
>>>from operator import contains
>>>contains([1,2,3], 2)
True
```